# Beautifulsoup find items in page with these attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

css class=`fb_pagZ`
and all the `li` `a` under this class.

So in css that would be: `fb_pagZ li a`, but I'm having trouble seeing how to represent it in beautifulsoup.

I currently have beautifulsoup code that finds all the classes on the page with `fb_pagZ` name, but i cannot seem to filter further down into the list items, specifically the `li a`, with only the `href` value being parsed.

`next_page_base=soup.find_all(class_='fb_pagZ')`

Example html output:

```
<div class="fb_pagZ">
<li><a href="site.com/img=2" /></li>
</div>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` selector of BeautifulSoup to do CSS style selection of elements.

So, based on your description, the following should do:

```
soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a')
```

Assuming, `soup` is a `BeautifulSoup` object.

Also note that, to select only the first element, use `select_one`:

```
soup.select_one('.fb_pagZ li a')
```

---

To iterate over the selections, and getting the `href` attribute's value:

```
for element in soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a'):
    href = element['href']
    # Do stuffs
```

---

When there is no such element present the output from `soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a')` would be a empty list, so the above iteration would not happen anyway.

If you want to be explicit about the emptiness:

```
# We're iterating over the pages, generating URLs
# e.g. if the pages come in querystrings in format
# `?page=2`, appending that and getting
# soup object for the final URL
elements = soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a')
if elements:
    for element in elements:
        href = element['href']
```

---

If you want to match on the `href` attribute too:

```
for element in soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a'):
    try:
        href = element['href']
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

or you can use `.get` and check against `None` (which is falsey):

```
for element in soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a'):
    href = element.get('href')
    if not href:
        continue
```

Comment: will `.select` select all occurances? Also, this doesnt extract the href attribute value. How can i do that (see updated question please)

Comment: @John Yes, it will.

Comment: its possible the site doesnt have `href` for the first page, is it possible to revise your code to skip this match and continue on? Currently for me, its failing altogether because the first match doesnt have `href` attribute

Comment: @Rakesh feel free to chime in if you'd like

Comment: problem with the updated code is this selector: `elements = soup.select('.fb_pagZ li a')` is selecting matches without `href` attribute, but I only want matches with `href`

Comment: This is working much better, but if `href` isnt in the url, it just prints `None` ? Anyway for this to just not print anything if its None?  I'm using your second example with `.get`

Comment: @John In my latest code, it does not print anything; it just skips the element (`continue`) and moves on to the next one.

Comment: Take that back, I added an else to the bottom and it fixed it. Thanks so much for the help heemayl!